# Is it ok if a machine is constantly at 85% of its physical memory?

Tags: caching, memory, ram

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask about hardware but I couldn't find a subforum for just monitoring hardware. If you know of one please direct me to it and I'll ask there.

I'm looking at a chart of physical memory on some front end machines and I was wondering if this was concerning.

[image]

Physical memory is constantly over 80% and free memory is always very low. The cached memory is decently high as well, with only 40% available at any given time. There's no information on available memory afaik.

I've tried visiting the front end site and there is no noticeable slowness in page load time. Most actions such as logins don't take long either, but there were recently some problems.

From google I learned that cached memory is memory that can be used faster than RAM and it looks like there's still a bit of available memory. Therefore I'm wondering whether the current load is alarming. Also, I'm not sure why the memory load dropped from the week of the 29th to the 31 or if that is concerning.

Comment: ya its ok  that a  machine is constantly at 85% of its physical memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you need to talk to someone who understands whatever application is running there, or (if it's not proprietary), ask a question about that application. Maybe it's deliberately managing most system memory itself?
2. the cache referred to here *is* RAM, and it's caching access to a slower device (usually disk). Your googling confused you by talking about the CPU cache, which is built in to the processor and won't show up on this graph

If you don't have some specific performance concern (observed slowness), it *may* not be an issue. Or it may mean you're at capacity, and adding one more user/customer/widget/whatever will cause a complete meltdown. There's no way to tell without more information.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that you have page swapping turned off in windows, and thus are utilizing more physical mem.